# Why is java.util.Calendar returning 31 for Feb 2021?

Tags: java, date, calendar, java-time

The following snippet returns:

```
28
31
```

I can't figure out, why. I tried so set the calendar object to Feb 2021 in two ways, what am I doing wrong?
Month is zero-based, so Feb is "1".

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        Calendar g = new GregorianCalendar(2021, 1, 28);
        System.out.println(g.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        

        int year = 2021;
        int month = 1;
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        System.out.println(c.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
     }
}
```

Or does this only happen, because I call Calendar.getInstance() on March 29, 30 or 31 and I don't call

```
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, {any day below 29});
```

Comment: Your `month` variable equals 1. It is January.

Comment: @talex it certainly is not. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.FEBRUARY

Comment: `Calendar` is a terrible class written by people who did not understand date-time handling. The legacy class was supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Do not waste your precious time wrestling with `Calendar`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You call [`Calendar.getInstance()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getInstance--), which returns a [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) object initialized to the current time, which today means Mar 31, 2021.

You then set `YEAR` to 2021 and `MONTH` to 1 (Feb), leaving `DAY_OF_MONTH` at 31. If you asked the `Calendar` object for the date, it would resolve the fields and return a date value that explains the issue:

```java
System.out.println(c.getTime()); // prints: Wed Mar 03 11:51:55 EST 2021
```

See how it says **Mar 3**, 2021? That is because Feb 31 rolls over after Feb 28 and becomes Mar 3.

Since the `Calendar` object is now in March, the `c.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)` correctly returns 31.

To do it right, call [`clear()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#clear--) and set `DAY_OF_MONTH` to 1, which is much easier when you use the nice [`set(year, month, date)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set-int-int-int-) helper method.

```java
int year = 2021;
int month = Calendar.FEBRUARY/*1*/;
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.clear();
c.set(year, month, 1);
System.out.println(c.getTime()); // prints: Mon Feb 01 00:00:00 EST 2021
System.out.println(c.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)); // prints: 28
```

Comment: That's what I thought what's happening. I found this bit of code in a legacy implementation of a service, that runs only once a month on the first day of the month. So, this never was an issue, until someone like me tested a configuration change on one of the few days a year, the code fails.
The code only fails on March 29-31 (30-31 in leap years), Mai 31, July 31, October 31 and December 31.

Answer (score 6):

`java.util` date-time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> .

**Using modern date-time API:**

```
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.Year;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(YearMonth.of(2021, Month.FEBRUARY).lengthOfMonth());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
28
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

**Using legacy API:**

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // 1st Feb 2021
        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(2021, Calendar.FEBRUARY, 1);
        System.out.println(cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
28
```

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Comment: Wouldn't [`YearMonth.of(2021, Month.FEBRUARY)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html#of-int-java.time.Month-) be simpler than `Year.of(2021).atMonth(Month.FEBRUARY)`? --- It for sure skips the wasted creation of a `Year` object.